# Setting an objects location to another object

Tags: c#

I'm making a racing game with intentionally terrible steering where the character pivots around the center of the map. The player also has the option to set the pivot point to their current location using the spacebar. It works less than 25% of the time. The code for this part of the code is

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown("space"))
    {
        PivotPoint.position = CharacterRotation.position;
    }
```

The rest of the code is here

```
    using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{   //movement
    public CharacterController characterController;
    public float speed = 6;
    private float hiddenSpeed = 6;
    public float sprintMultiplier = 1.75f;
    //rotation
    public Transform CharacterRotation;
    public Transform PivotPoint;
    //gravity
    public float gravity = 5f;
    private float verticalSpeed = 0;
    //camera and camera rotation
    public Transform cameraHolder;
    public float mouseSensitivity = 2f;
    public float upLimit = -50;
    public float downLimit = 50;

    void start()
    {
        hiddenSpeed = speed;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        Move();
        Rotate();
        Inputs();
    }

    private void Move()
    {   //movement
        float horizontalMove = 0;
        float verticalMove = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        //gravity
        if (characterController.isGrounded) verticalSpeed = 0;
        else verticalSpeed -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
        //move update
        Vector3 gravityMove = new Vector3(0, verticalSpeed, 0);
        Vector3 move = transform.forward * verticalMove + transform.right * horizontalMove;
        characterController.Move(speed * Time.deltaTime * move + gravityMove * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    public void Rotate()
    {
        float horizontalRotation = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float verticalRotation = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");

        transform.Rotate(0, horizontalRotation * mouseSensitivity, 0);
        cameraHolder.Rotate(-verticalRotation * mouseSensitivity, 0, 0);

        Vector3 currentRotation = cameraHolder.localEulerAngles;
        if (currentRotation.x > 180) currentRotation.x -= 360;
        currentRotation.x = Mathf.Clamp(currentRotation.x, upLimit, downLimit);
        cameraHolder.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(currentRotation);
    }
    public void Inputs()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("space"))
        {
            PivotPoint.position = CharacterRotation.position;
        }

        if (Input.GetKey("r"))
        {
            CharacterRotation.position = new Vector3(0f, .133f, 0f);
            PivotPoint.position = new Vector3(0f, .133f, 0f);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please clarify - when you say it works 25% of the time, what behaviour do you see the other 75%? Is it using the wrong location, or is it missing the spacebar key press?

Comment: Most of the time the cube moves to twice the current radius, when only the pivot point should be moving while the cube stays still.